# Replace part of the xml , navigation component

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment(A) which contains a frameLayout . I want in the place of the frameLayout to place another fragment(B)  so that i have them both after i press a button. How can i do this using navigation component? Because when i try to, the whole fragment A gets replaced by fragment B .

Answer (score 0):

If you are replacing just a part of Fragment A's layout, then you should be using [child fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#child) by doing a `FragmentTransaction` on the [childFragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getChildFragmentManager()).

The Navigation Component always replaces the entire contents of the `NavHostFragment`.

Comment: when using navigation, the fragment's state gets saved. If I use FragmentTransaction, when recreated, the information will get lost.

Comment: All Navigation is doing for you *is* a FragmentTransaction, there's nothing special there that you can't also do.

Comment: i looked through this after your answer and i got a better undrestanding of the fragments & navigation that lead me to find the solution needed. Thank you!!